# How to load Application.properties file dynamically based on Profile in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am learning Spring MVC and I want to know How to load application.properties file dynamically.

I am adding HibernateConfig.java file and AppConfig.java file. I want to load application properties file dynamically using profiles. For Example: dev, test, prod. I have tried to use dynamic name **application-{profile}.properties** and also tried profile annotation. but not able to understand how they are actually working. I have created a different application.properties files.

1. application-dev
2. application-test
3. application-prod

This property file contains my DB related data. but I don't know how to set profile and how to load PropertySource based on a profile.
I have set the active profile in my appConfig file. Please help me in understanding how to configure profile and application.properties using spring MVC Java-based configuration. I have searched and found many solutions for XML based configuration but I haven't found any proper answer for java based configuration.

> HibernateConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.project.configuration"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
return sessionFactory;      
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
/* loading DB */
return dataSource;  
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties(){
}
}
```

> AppConfig.java

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
{
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant set this parameter at that time, its already too late. You have to start the app with specified profile (or set it in bootstrap file) . You can pass it as an argument or place it in:
application.properities 
Under key: spring.profiles.active

When you set this to 'dev' it will read main application.properities and then the profile one. More about how to set it:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: I have tried to put spring.profiles.active in application.properties. But It is giving me an error and I am not sure it will work in Spring MVC. spring.profiles.active is for spring boot only.